# How i can run nextjs web app into angular web app without using iframe

Tags: reactjs, angular, next.js13, umd

How i can run mu nextjs web app into angular web app without using iframe.
i would like to embed it in another web app.
i have tried creating nexjs app as library but it does not work.
i want to create umd module of nextjs app.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Reverse Proxy

One of the cleanest ways to integrate a Next.js app into an Angular app is to set up a reverse proxy. You can use a server like Nginx or a reverse proxy module to route requests to the appropriate application based on URL paths